# Sass cocantenate strings without space

Tags: sass

I have what I thought was a simple question. By default, Sass cocantenates variables by placing a space between the values. I have a pair of strings I want to cocantenate to form a complete URL string:

```
$img: "../img/";
$header-bg: $img+"header-bg.png";
```

Outputs as:

```
"../img/ header-bg.png";
```

Output wanted:

```
"../img/header-bg.png";
```

How do I prevent that default space from being inserted?

Thanks all!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, space does not appear in any Sass version I can test with on [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try inserting the first variable into the second string using this method.

```
$img: "../img/";
$header-bg: "#{$img}header-bg.png";
```